# Grafana alert is created with new alerting provisioning api, but not actually working

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-api

I am creating an alert for grafana using this endpoint `POST /api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules` with the bellow  request body. The created alert is shown in the UI, but on the health column it's showing either an error, with the message `failed to execute conditions: data source not found`, or `nodata`.

The alert structure used is: a query, like sum by(instance) (<metric>{job=<jobname>}), a expression of type reducer and a expression of type math.

Grafana version: 9.1.6

Request body:

```
{
  orgID: 1,
  folderUID: '<fodler_uid>',
  ruleGroup: '<rule_group>',
  title: '<alert_name>/de6835e3-148f-4cef-9b53-9fcf0afa1f65',
  condition: 'C',
  noDataState: 'NoData',
  execErrState: 'Error',
  data: [
    {
      refId: 'A',
      queryType: '',
      relativeTimeRange: { from: 300, to: 0 },
      datasourceUid: '<datasource_id>',
      model: {
        expr: 'sum by(instance) (<metric_name>{job="<environment_name>"})',
        hide: false,
        intervalMs: 1000,
        maxDataPoints: 43200,
        refId: 'A'
      }
    },
    {
      refId: 'B',
      queryType: '',
      relativeTimeRange: { from: 0, to: 0 },
      datasourceUid: '-100',
      model: {
        conditions: [
          {
            evaluator: { params: [ 3 ], type: 'gt' },
            operator: { type: 'and' },
            query: { params: [ 'A' ] },
            reducer: { params: [], type: 'last' },
            type: 'query'
          }
        ],
        datasource: { type: '__expr__', uid: '-100' },
        expression: 'A',
        hide: false,
        intervalMs: 1000,
        maxDataPoints: 43200,
        reducer: 'last',
        refId: 'B',
        type: 'reduce'
      }
    },
    {
      refId: 'C',
      queryType: '',
      relativeTimeRange: { from: 0, to: 0 },
      datasourceUid: '-100',
      model: {
        conditions: [
          {
            evaluator: { params: [ 0, 0 ], type: 'gt' },
            operator: { type: 'and' },
            query: { params: [ 'B' ] },
            reducer: { params: [], type: 'avg' },
            type: 'query'
          }
        ],
        datasource: { name: 'Expression', type: '__expr__', uid: '__expr__' },
        expression: '$B > 100',
        intervalMs: 1000,
        maxDataPoints: 43200,
        refId: 'C',
        type: 'math'
      }
    }
  ],
  for: '1m',
  annotations: {},
  labels: {}
}
```

[ERROR Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfSkV.png)

I've tried using the post object that is send from grafana when a alert is created from UI. Also I've tried to modify my object with the properties from the UI request object. I've expected a working alert, but in these cases the api returns a bad request.

I don't know what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you'll don't get answer here, I advise to go to https://community.grafana.com/ and posting this question there. I believe you'll have better chance of getting qualified answer there.

Comment: I've already posted on their community last week and still no answer, so I said to try here